# Lifetime inference for container objects inside closures

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, inference

I have a routine that plays with objects in a container and references to those objects stored in another 2 containers.
However,  I am not finding the rust way of doing this, the lifetime inference seems to forbid this and I don't know how to resolve it

```
fn main() {
    let mut deck : Deck = Deck::new();
    let mut p1 : Hand = Hand::new();
    let mut p2 : Hand = Hand::new();


    do_hands(|data: &[Card]| -> Result<(),()> {
      for card in data {
        deck.insert(card.id, CardCell::new(*card));

        let card: &CardCell = deck.get_mut(&card.id).unwrap();
        handle_hand(&mut card, &mut p1, &mut p2);

      }      
      return Ok(());
    });

}
```

Here is the full playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6079ade83e3fcf06f35397eac2e82d05&version=nightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with the example in the playground and managed to get the code to compile, with the following changes:

1. Change the signature of `handle_hand`

   The initial signature was `fn handle_hand<'a>(_card: &'a mut CardCell, _p1: &mut Hand<'a>, _p2: &mut Hand<'a>)`, but this was what the compiler error is about. This signature requires all input to `handle_hand` to have the same lifetime, but that is not the case in your code. There, inside the closure, `card` clearly has a shorted lifetime than `p1` and `p2`. So the revised signature simply becomes: `fn handle_hand<'a, 'b>(_card: &'b mut CardCell, _p1: &mut Hand<'a>, _p2: &mut Hand<'a>)`.
2. Change the signature of `card` inside the closure.

   Since `handle_hand` requires a `&mut CardCell`, you must then declare `card` as `let mut card: &mut CardCell =...`
3. Derive the copy trait into the `Card` struct. I put this last since this may need to be changed depending on how you'd further write the struct. But at this point, it's just a wrapper of `u64`, and you can simply do `#[derive(Clone, Copy]` on it. This is required because the `Cell` struct you are using [requires a Copy type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#impl). Derive works here because all your struct's fields already implement the Copy type.

[Here's the updated playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8c7fc05964a3a2f808bb2940eb8a4c54&version=nightly).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but the moment I do that it prevents me from storing the CardCell reference into p1 or p2, consider this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b1dc8cb220daca0efaa0e5a6b4501786&version=nightly

Comment: Aha, I don't think the reference to `_card` can be stored inside `p1` or `p2` as-is know because `card` has a shorted lifetime than `p1`/`p2`, since it is created within the closure.

In other words, you may need to create `card` outside the closure; so that it has the same lifetime  as `p1`/`p2`.

Comment: hmm, so I might need to change the way the code is working, I cannot create the card outside because I need the parameter of the closure to create the card, then store it in the container and then, in reality, might change it a bit and then store it in either p1 or p2.

Comment: I think so indeed. I changed the `handle_card` signature so that it works given the current setup: creating the card inside the closure. But if you do intend to push back to `p1`/`p2`, the card has to be created in another way that ensures its reference lives as long as `p1`/`p2`.